# PyCharm: How to reduce horizontal use of space

Tags: pycharm

I Like to set up PyCharm to have a terminal, a code editor and the structure view side by side to maximize the vertical space for each. This makes sense since each of those generally isn't very wide, and screens are very wide these days. On my laptop, I'm kind of running out of horizontal space, especially when code uses 115 text columns. But I also see a lot of 'wasted' space.

[image]

So my question is, how do I get PyCharm to use less horizontal space?

I've searched the settings and Google, but I couldn't find anything about how to do the following

1. The buttons for the terminal (+, x) should be in the header (or remove the button bar altogether).
2. The Divider bar between the terminal and the editor doesn't have to be 2 characters wide.
3. The space between line numbers and the editor could be reduced or removed (break points could just sit on top of the line numbers).
4. The structure view doesn't need to have root entry for the filename, with all children and thus being indented.
   5.) The structure view uses a lot of unnecessary indentation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Those are decent points and unfortunately I don't have any good answers for it. On (1), there isn't a customization. On (2), I suspect it comes from the UI toolkit. On (3) though, there's more than just breakpoints that go in the left gutter. On (4), I don't know what else besides __builtins__ can be at the top level. I'd focus on (4), as it is almost as much space as the others combined. Can you file a feature request?

Answer (score 0):

For #1 right-click on the Terminal's top bar or its toolbar tab (works for any tool) and you'll get a popup menu in which you can de-select the `Show Toolbar` option:

[image]

All the tools that can show up in the left/right sidebars can be:

- moved to the bottom toolbar (using the `Move to` options in the above-mentioned popup menu), thus chewing vertical space instead of horizontal space
- hidden when not used (by simple click on the tools' toolbar tab), the remaining displayed panes are automatically extended to fill the horizontal space
- completely decoupled in separate, independent windows by selecting the `Windowed Mode` in the above-mentioned popup menu. My personal preference is to do that at least with the `Terminal` (as well as the `Run` and `Inspect`) windows, I rarely need them in the *same* window as the code. Check out the other modes or their combinations as well, maybe something looks better for you.

Finally, you *might* like the `View` -> `Enter Distraction Free Mode` option :)